# PayPal Smart Payment Buttons - validate shipping address before payment?

Tags: paypal

PayPal allows adding a delivery address street without a number.

As far as I know, it is not possible to check this behavior during the order process before the payment is finished.

The order data is available in the `onApprove` function scope.
But that's too late, because the payment is finished then?

Is there a way to add address validation?

```html
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=abc123&disable-funding=credit,card,sepa,giropay&currency=EUR"></script>
<script>
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
        return fetch('/paypal/order/create/', {
            method: 'post'
        }).then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(orderData) {

            if (orderData.error)
            {
                return actions.reject();
            }

            return orderData.id;
        });
    },
    onShippingChange: function(data, actions) {
        
        if (data.shipping_address.country_code !== 'DE') 
        {
            return actions.reject();
        }

        return actions.resolve();
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
        
        return fetch('/paypal/order/' + data.orderID + '/capture/', {
            method: 'post'
        }).then(function(res) 
        {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(orderData) {
        
            let re = /[0-9]/;
            
            // test
            if (re.exec(orderData.payer.address.address_line_1) === null)
            {
                // cancle payment on this place is to late, because payment is finished
            }

            var errorDetail = Array.isArray(orderData.details) && orderData.details[0];
            
            if (errorDetail && errorDetail.issue === 'INSTRUMENT_DECLINED') {
                return actions.restart(); 
            }

            if (errorDetail) 
            {
               return;
            }

            return fetch('/paypal/finish-order/' + data.orderID + '/',{
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify(orderData),
                method: 'post'
                }).then(function(result){
                    let dat = result.json();
                    return dat;
                }).then(function(data)
                {
                    if (data.error)
                    {
                        actions.reject();
                    }

                    if (data.destination)
                    {
                        actions.redirect(data.destination)
                    }
                });
        });
    },
    funding: {
        allowed: [ paypal.FUNDING.CARD ],
        disallowed: [ paypal.FUNDING.CREDIT ]
    },
    style: {
        size: 'medium',
        height: 40,
        label: 'checkout'
    }

}).render('#ppbut');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When onApprove is called, the payment is not finished. The order still needs to be captured.

- Before capture, you can show an order review step if desired (for the customer to verify a new total, for example, or select from available shipping methods).  This step can be done by updating the DOM dynamically (a redirect can also work but is best avoided).
- If the address is invalid, show an error message accordingly and give an option to restart; do not proceed with any capture. You do not need to void the order (there is no method), simply forget about that order id and never capture it.
- You can [patch the order](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch) to a new total as needed (automatically, or based on selections in the review step you add).
- Finally, proceed with the capture as normal and show success.

---

If you do add a user review step after approval, you should also change the last button at PayPal to say "Continue" instead of the default "Pay Now" to match your behavior. This is only a text change, the behavior only changes based on what you do in onApprove, which must correspond. To make the text change, add an application_context object to the top level (not inside purchase_units) of your order creation request, in which you specify a user_action parameter with the value `CONTINUE`.

Comment: Reading your question more closely though, perhaps you aren't aware that addresses **without a number** can be valid in many places https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-have-an-address-without-a-house-number

Comment: Also, you're already using an onShippingChange callback to only ship to DE? In that case you can also reject the address there based on any other criteria you want.  A disadvantage of using onShippingChange is that the black "Debit or Credit" card button currently won't be able to load inline (and instead fall back to opening a window), but it seems you've disabled that payment method anyway.  To always only render a single button yo should specify the funding source https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/standalone-buttons/  : `fundingSource: paypal.FUNDING.PAYPAL,`

Comment: onShippingChange will not give me the full address data.

shipping_address:
city: "freiburg"
country_code: "DE"
postal_code: "77777"
state: ""

Comment: Ah alright; I suppose it does make sense for the precise address to be private without a completed transaction.

Comment: Can you describe the first step. Before capture, you can... ! I looked into the responses before capture. The address data are not send within these responses.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/sdk/js/reference from the documentation its not clear, how to solve the problem.

Comment: Use the orders API to get details https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#orders_get